# How to transform all that not white is on display to black and reverse using tools like xcalib

Tags: xorg, xrandr

I want to make my complete display looking as really black and white. This is justified by the fact that I want the text in my browser to be as contrasting as possible. Most pages in the browser have a white background. I want this white background to be converted to black, and everything that is not white to white. I'm currently using the `xcalib -i -a` command, but often the text in the browser is gray and I don't get the contrast I want. Naturally, I need a command that would reset the display settings to default when, for example, I watch a video in the browser.